# consideration to speedup tcp/udp connection

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, udp, winsock2

I'm using `winsock2` library to write a SDK(Software Developement Kit) for a digital board with 1Gbps ethernet on it. the problem I'm facing is that I  can not get enough transfer rate(TX/RX) through ethernet uing TCP/UDP. i rather use UDP-RX as a case study to understand each parameter than can speed up my connection. with the code below i can send data from my PC to my device in just ~350 Mbps.

Start Listening:

```
//Initialize winsock library
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &m_wsa) != 0)
{
    error = WSAGetLastError();
}
//Create a socket
if ((m_serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    error = WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}
int buffersize = 0x200000;
int buffersizelen = sizeof(buffersize);
setsockopt(m_serversocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&buffersize, buffersizelen);
//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
memset(&m_serveraddress, 0, sizeof(m_serveraddress));
m_serveraddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_Address, &m_serveraddress.sin_addr.s_addr);
m_serveraddress.sin_port = htons(SEND_PORT_number);
// Bind the socket to any address and the specified port.
if (bind(m_serversocket, (struct sockaddr *)&m_serveraddress, sizeof(m_serveraddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    error = WSAGetLastError();
    return;
}
```

Sending file:

```
    sendchunk = 1000;
    // Read File and fill the buffer 
    if ((m_err = fopen_s(&m_send_file, m_send_filename.toLocal8Bit().data(), "rb")) == 0)
    {
        // start to send buffer
        while (!(feof(m_send_file) || m_stopsend))
        {
            remainsize = fread(read_data, 1, sendfilesize / count, m_send_file);
            sndsize_ProgBar += remainsize;
            sentsize = 0;
            timer.start();
            while ((remainsize >= sendchunk) && !(m_stopsend))
            {
                sendto(m_serversocket, read_data + sentsize, sendchunk, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&m_serveraddress, addrlengh); // 1024
                sentsize += sendchunk;
                remainsize -= sendchunk;
            }
            elapsedtimemicrosec = timer.getElapsedTimeInMicroSec();
            timer.stop(); 
            rcvRate = (float)(((remainsize + sentsize)) / elapsedtimemicrosec);
            emit UpdateSendRate(rcvRate);
        }
    }
```

any suggestion to speedup connection?

P.S: i already tried different `sendchunk` and choose the best.

Comment: There are some bits missing from the code but... are you sure it's the network/protocol that's the limiting factor here and not the rate at which the file is being read from disk?

Comment: @G.M. i reduce code size to make it easier to understand. as you can see in my code timer is start and stop exactly before and after  the `sendto` function. so: NO, read file latency has not been counted in the connection speed.